# Split folder into subfolders with the name of that subfolder dependent on file name prefix

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a folder with 8857429 files stored within it. Each file follows the same naming structure: "{GROUP}-{UNIX TIMESTAMP}"

I want each group to have its subfolder containing all files that match the group.

How can I achieve this in ubuntu using bash?

**Example of what I want:**

*Input:*

```
DATA/
├── A-1.txt
├── A-2.txt
├── A-3.txt
├── B-1.txt
├── B-2.txt
├── B-3.txt
├── C-1.txt
├── C-2.txt
└── C-3.txt
```

*Output:*

```
DATA/
├── A/
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   └── 3.txt
├── B/
│   ├── 1.txt
│   ├── 2.txt
│   └── 3.txt
└── C/
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 3.txt
```

Comment: Something as simple as this may address your needs: `mkdir $(ls *.txt | cut -d- -f1 | sort -u)` and `rename 's#-#/#'  *.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the script below and save it as a file named `./move_files.sh` at the same level as the `DATA` directory (i.e. not inside the `DATA` directory).
2. Make the file executable by executing...

   ```
   chmod +x move_files.sh
   ```
3. Run this script by executing...

   ```
   ./move_files.sh
   ```

   I recommend testing this script on a copy of your `DATA` directory, to ensure you get the results you expect. I only tested it on the exact sample you shard in your question.

---

Here is the script `move_files.sh`...

```
#!/bin/bash

# move_files.sh
#
# Creates group folders based on file name prefixes, and then renames
# and moves the files into the corresponding group folders.
#
# All files must be in the "DATA" directory.
# All files must follow the naming structure "{GROUP}-{UNIX TIMESTAMP}".
#
# Remember to make this script executable using `chmod +x move_files.sh`.
# Save this script at the same level as the DATA directory.
# Run this script using `./move_files.sh`

cd "DATA"
count=0
for file_name in *; do
    # Remove the prefix from the file name.
    new_file_name=${file_name#*-}
    # Remove the suffix from the file name.
    group=${file_name%"-$new_file_name"}
    # Print information.
    ((count=count+1))
    echo "${count}. Move file \"${new_file_name}\" into directory \"${group}\"."
    # Create a group directory, if it does not exist.
    mkdir --parents "${group}"
    # Move the file into the group directory, and use the new file name.
    mv "${file_name}" "${group}/${new_file_name}"
done
```

Comment: Testing right now! If this works, it'll be perfect!

Comment: It might take a bit to make a backup as the folder is 35GB.

Comment: Be sure to use the script with my final updates (just corrections to comments) about 4 minutes ago.

Comment: Will do! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I could upvote! Sadly, I need 15 reputation to do that.